# reset black, white and grey point

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was playing with curves and i've set the black, white and grey point and now every time i use Auto Color Correction it's calculating using those colors, how do i reset those points?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want full defaults, set it to 'Enhance Brightness & Contrast'.

If you want to reset your colours whilst remaining in 'Enhance Monochrome Contrast' mode, then the defaults are [top to bottom]

*RGB*
0,0,0
128,128,128
255,255,255

ie, Black, mid-grey, white. Clips are OK at 0.10.

Check the "Save as defaults" box and click ok.